# How to see current cache size when using functools.lru_cache?

Tags: python

I am doing performance/memory analysis on a certain method that is wrapped with the `functools.lru_cache` decorator. I want to see how to inspect the current size of my cache without doing some crazy inspect magic to get to the underlying cache.

Does anyone know how to see the current cache size of method decorated with `functools.lru_cache`?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Yes. The only reason I posted here as a knowledge share (I answered below), was to provide an easy answer to people searching for this in the future. It took me awhile to find it, and so I wanted to make it easier for others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Digging around in the docs showed the answer is calling `.cache_info()` on the method.

> To help measure the effectiveness of the cache and tune the maxsize parameter, the wrapped function is instrumented with a cache_info() function that returns a named tuple showing hits, misses, maxsize and currsize. In a multi-threaded environment, the hits and misses are approximate.